# Wave file not being found in OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, windows

I've found this nice piece of code to open wav files:

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
open.Filter = "Wave File (*.wav)|*.wav;";
if (open.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
{
    return;
}
```

However the problem is that it will not see the wave file.

[image: File not present]

But I can see it through Windows Explorer:

[image: File present]

The problem doesn't exist for txt or jpg images.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `;` from pattern

```
open.Filter = "Wave File (*.wav)|*.wav";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the reason why I'm having so many problems with file types etc. with Visual Studio Community 2015.

The reason is that I had being using windows 10 and when I reinstalled it on Windows 8.1 there was no issues.
The issue must lie with 10 not being ready for development or **PEBKAC**!!!

:-)